# how would you translate כמה דתימא

Tags: words

In Midrash Rabbah Bereshit we have היך מה דאת אמר first (as you read [verse]). But then Rabba HaOshaya uses this expression  כמה דתימא and he quotes a verse. The last part דתימא i don't understand how we should translate it? and why ? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Lehava. Unfortunately, questions asking us to translate Hebrew (or Aramaic) statements are off topic here. If you want to [edit] in how this is related to Judaism (perhaps it's from a specific Gemara?), that would be on topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

כמה דתימא means "as it says". תימא is Aramaic for "said", with the root אמר (often spelled אמא).